# javascript loading error

Tags: javascript

I don't know why, but after I move all my files to the server and run it. There seems to be an error with the javascript.. It's adding an extra `</br>` as you can see on the image below. Reason is why and how do I fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the screenshot your `.js` file contains HTML. That cannot work...

If it works on your local server, ask your server administrator for help.